# Title gets undefined when hovered (jQuery UI Tooltip)

Tags: jquery

The following code is run every second in setInterval:

```
for (i = 0; i < mt1.length; i++){
    $(mt1[i]).each(function(){
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).attr('title').split(" ")[0] + " " + $(this).attr('title').split(" ")[1]);
    });
}

title = "<img src='/flags/4x3/cn.svg' width='20px'' height='20px'> " + accounting.formatMoney(accounting.unformat($(this).html().split(" ")[0].substr(2).slice(0, -1)) * -6, '¥', 2, ",", ".");
$(this).attr('title', title + '|' + $(this).attr('title'));
```

What is happening is when not hovered, inspecting the element shows all correctly, the text is blinking every second as stated in the `setInterval()` method: `<span title="55 tests |<img src='/flags/4x3/cn.svg' width='20px'' height='20px'> ¥1.90</span>`

But after it gets hovered, it shows `undefined` instead of `55 tests`. What's happening?

This is shown in `console.log` after hovering:

```
undefined |<img src='/flags/4x3/cn.svg' width='20px'' height='20px'> ¥1.90
```

> UPDATE:

Seems like `tooltip (jQueryUI Tooltip)` I am using has something to do with it, the next code is in the beginning of the page. What is does, is turns `|` to `<br>` to move currency value to the next line:

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
        content: function(callback)
        {
            callback($(this).prop('title').replace(/\|/g, '<br />'));
        }
    })
});
```

> UPDATE: JSFiddle added:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/hrkLssgk/][1]
```

Comment: It looks like your title attribute starts with a double quote, but ends with a single quote? Can you provide a jsfiddle so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: you have extra quote on attribute width.

Comment: Theres an extra `'` in `width='20px''`. What plugin are you using?

Comment: I tried it, but it still turns `undefined`. I am using accounting.js.

Comment: @TennysonH, here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/hrkLssgk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if you needed your code to be in a setInterval, so I left it. Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hrkLssgk/2/

Notice we've changed your array to contain a updated flag for each element. Once the element has had it's title updated, it does not go through the updating again until the flag is reverted.

```
var mt1 = [
    [$("#la"), false] /* first element is jquery, second is flag if it's been updated */
];
```

iterate through each element, and only execute title-change if it's flag is false:

```
mt1.forEach(function(){
        if (!mt1[i][1]) {
```

if setInterval is not necessary, you would be better off moving this logic outside of the setInterval and into a function that is called when needed